# What is wrong with this query with DISTINCT keyword?

Tags: mysql, sql, distinct

I want to display `dishname` and `dishprice` with `DISTINCT` value of 2nd highest `dishprice`.

What is the problem with the following query?

```
SELECT dishName, DISTINCT(dishPrice) FROM `tblDish` ORDER BY dishPrice LIMIT 1,1
```

Comment: The problem is that the set you wish to obtain is not properly defined.

Comment: Need to sort in descending order, but obvious meaning of DISTINCT is not clear in question

Comment: then how to declare it... can you please give correct query?

Comment: Put some example records and result in the question,then it may be helpful.

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected result.

Comment: result would like to display as

dishName   dishPrice
name 1      300(2nd largest price in table)

Comment: do you want the 2nd highest price for each dish, or the dish with the 2nd highest price among all dishes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case there are more then one record for same price then need to group them bye price and group concat all the records

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(dishName), dishPrice FROM `tblDish` GROUP BY dishPrice ORDER BY dishPrice DESC LIMIT 1,1
```

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT(dishPrice), dishName FROM `tblDish` GROUP BY `dishPrice` ORDER BY `dishPrice` LIMIT 1,1
```

You should always mention Distinction before selecting any other column of the table

Comment: use backticks instead of quote for  'dishPrice'

Answer (score 1):

use GROUP BY with the query. So, you can list and differentiate with their categories.